# Why google form apps script form addsectionheaderitem adds a question item but not a layout item?

Tags: google-apps-script

google form apps script, the following code generate a question item that asks for answer, but not a section header just displaying title or helptext

```
var item = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
item.setTitle(info);
```

when checking the item type with gettype(), it shows type of sectionheader correctly, yet, displays an input box for answer

Does anyone has similar experience? and how to overcome this?

```
function makeQuestionsForm(sheetID, formName) {
  var spreadsheetId = sheetID;
  var rangeName = 'A2:E';
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;

  var id = '';

  if (!values) {
    Logger.log('No data found.');
  } else {
    // Create and open a form with the given formName.
    var newForm = FormApp.create(formName);
    id = newForm.getId();
    form = FormApp.openById(id);
    var item;
    for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
      if (values[row][2] == 'ginto') {
        form.addSectionHeaderItem().setHelpText(values[row][3]);
      } else {
        if (values[row][2] == 'mcq') {
          addMCQ(values[row][1], values[row][3], values[row][4])
        } else {
          addFRQ(values[row][1],values[row][3])
        }
      }
    }

  }
  return id
}
```

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Api2E.png)

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what your current  and what the desired result is? Screenshots might help understanding your issue better.

Comment: Thanks ziganotschka. I am trying to generate a dynamic form that includes groups of questions sharing some common information. My plan is to put the common information as helptext of a sectionheader. I have no problem of generating questions. the problem is that the sectionheader becomes  like a short answer question, displaying an input box after the title or helptext of the sectionheader.

Comment: Hi, ziganotschka. I've updated the question with the code and a screenshot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The following code snippet creates a section header without an answer box:

```js
function makeQuestionsForm(sheetID, formName) {
  var spreadsheetId = sheetID;
  var rangeName = 'A2:E';
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;

  var id = '';
  var row = 0;
  // Create and open a form with the given formName.
  var newForm = FormApp.create("formName");
  id = newForm.getId();
  form = FormApp.openById(id);
  form.addSectionHeaderItem().setHelpText("values[row][3]");
  console.log(id)
}
```

Thus, the error must come from the functions being executed within you `if...else` statements or the conditions when those functions are being called.

I recommend you to run those functions one by one to troubleshoot and also implement logs within each conditional statement to verify that the functions are called under the correct condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ziganotschka. Yes, it turns out to be a problem of conditional statement.